# Reading two mazes in a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, maze

I'm trying to figure out how to read two or more mazes from the same text file.

Here's my main method but it reads only one maze and I want to read two mazes and solve it separately. Can anybody explain to me how?

```
String fileName = "Maze.txt";

try {
        String readline;

        FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            int line = 0;

            while((readline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(readline); //loads the maze

                char[] charArr = readline.toCharArray();
                maze[line] = charArr;

                line++;

            }

    br.close();         
}
```

The `Maze.txt` file should look like this

```
 000100000000000
 000100001000010  
 000111111111000   
 000100000001000  
 000111110001000  
 000000010001000  
 000011110001000  
 000010010001010  
 000010010000000  
 000010000000000  
 000011111110000  
 000000000010000  
 000000000010000  
 000001000011110  
 000000000010000 

 010000000000000  
 010000000000000  
 010000000000000  
 011100000000000  
 000111110001000  
 011100010000000  
 000100010001000  
 000000010001000  
 000000011111100  
 000000000000100  
 000000000000100  
 000000001111100  
 000000000000100  
 000000000000100  
 000000000000100
```

Comment: I think that your second maze is not read because of the blank line, please run debug to check it out

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  you need to test to see if the line that you read is a blank line.  For example `if (readLine.trim().equals("")) { ...`

Hint 2: you need to decide if you method should "read all mazes in a file", or "read the next maze in from a stream".